# Getting a score with submit

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am making a website page that is a survey of sorts. I have one section mostly working but I can't get the second half. I used the same code as the first section and expanded. I can't get it to work though. I don't understand why it won't write the score when I hit submit. When I press submit it should write over "this is the answer" and should calculate the number of points from the value of the questions so for example, if they press the first radio button for each question it should print 2.

This is the base JavaScript I used in case it helps.

```
 function answer(total) {
 var score = 0;
if (document.getElementById('exp_no').checked) {
score++;
}
if (document.getElementById('chg_no').checked) {
score++;
}
if (document.getElementById('sus_no').checked) {
score++;
}
document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = score;

}
```

This is the JavaScript I am using.

```
function answer2(total) {
var score2 = 0;
if (document.getElementById('arr_1').checked) {
score2++;
}
else if (document.getElementById('arr_2').checked) {
score2 + 2;
}
else if (document.getElementById('arr_3').checked) {
score2 + 3;
}
else if (document.getElementById('arr_4').checked) {
score2 + 4;
}
else (document.getElementById('arr_5').checked) {
score2 + 5;
}

if (document.getElementById('been1').checked) {
score2++;
}
else if (document.getElementById('been2').checked) {
score2 + 2;
}
else if (document.getElementById('been3').checked) {
score2 + 3;
}
else if (document.getElementById('been4').checked) {
score2 + 4;
}
else if (document.getElementById('been5').checked) {
score2 + 5;
}
if (score2 == 2) {
document.getElementById('finalScore').innerHTML = score2;
} else if (score2 == 4){
document.getElementById('finalScore').innerHTML = score2;
} else if (score2 == 4){
document.getElementById('finalScore').innerHTML = score2;
} else if (score2 == 6){
document.getElementById('finalScore').innerHTML = score2;
} else if (score2 == 8){
document.getElementById('finalScore').innerHTML = score2;
} else if (score2 == 10){
document.getElementById('finalScore').innerHTML = score2;
}
}
```

This is my HTML

```
<button onclick = "toggletab()" id="tabButton"><h3>first results</h3>
</button>
       <form>
         <div id="first"  >
         <fieldset>
                <label>
                <legend>Is your arrest record a:</legend>
                    <input id="arr_1" type="radio" name="field4" value="1" 
onclick="getscores4(this)"/>
                    IC 35-38-9-1
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input id="arr_2" type="radio" name="field4" value="2" 
onclick="getscores4(this)"/>
                    IC 35-38-9-2
                </label>
                 <label>
                    <input id="arr_3" type="radio" name="field4" value="3" 
onclick="getscores4(this)"/>
                     IC 35-38-9-3
                </label>
                 <label>
                    <input id="arr_4" type="radio" name="field4" value="4" 
onclick="getscores4(this)"/>
                     IC 35-38-9-4
                </label>
                 <label>
                    <input id="arr_5" type="radio" name="field4" value="5" 
 onclick="getscores4(this)"/>
                     IC 35-38-9-5
                </label>
            </fieldset>


          <fieldset>
          <label>
                <legend>Has it been:</legend>
                    <input id="been1" type="radio" name="field5" value="1" 
 onclick="getscores5(this)"/>
                1 Year From Date of Arrestor earlier if the Prosecutor 
 agrees
                </label>
                 <label>
                    <input id="been2" type="radio" name="field5" value="2" 
onclick="getscores5(this)"/>
                     5 Years From Date of Arrestor earlier if the Prosecutor 
agrees
                </label>
                 <label>
                    <input id="been3" type="radio" name="field5" value="3" 
onclick="getscores5(this)"/>
                     8 YearsFrom Date of Arrestor earlier if the Prosecutor 
agrees
                </label>
                 <label>
                    <input id="been4" type="radio" name="field5" value="4" 
 onclick="getscores5(this)"/>
                     8/3 Years The Later of 8 Years from Date of Conviction 
or 3 years from completion of the sentence or earlier if the Prosecutor 
agrees
                </label>
                 <label>
                    <input id="been5" type="radio" name="field5" value="5" 
onclick="getscores5(this)"/>
                     10/5 Years The Later of 10 Years from Date of 
Conviction or 5 years from completion of the  sentence or earlier if the 
Prosecutor agrees
                </label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <fieldset id="submitbutton" class="article">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick='answer2()' />
<p id="finalScore">this is answer </p>
</fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>

        <script src="backtest.js"></script>
        <script src="backtest2.js"></script>
        <script src="toggle.js"></script>
```

Comment: This snippet have lot of issues.What exactly you want to do?

Comment: I need to have the values of the questions added. I am planning to have 5 different results depending on if the final value is equal to 2, 4, 6, 8 or 10. This should display result # depending on what number the final value is equal to. So if arr_1 and been1 are selected the final value should be 2 and display result 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function answer2(total) you have declared variable with name 'score2' but in all your logic you are using variable with name 'score'. Change score to score2 then it will work. And I also think that there is no need for argument 'total' in answer2() function because you are not using it anywhere.